# iOS app not resuming the sound state after returning from background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tvos

I am trying to build an iOS app which plays a sound. there is a button for On and Off. the button is working fine when we are inside the app. However, it is not working the way it needs to work if we r in the background.

Say the sound is in the OFF state, we r outside the app (app is still in the background), now if we open any other app and return to my app, the sound is supposed to be in OFF state, but it is turned ON. Same happens for the other state too (ON to OFF).

Here is the code I am using.

```
func SetUpSound() {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "firenew", ofType: "mp3") {
        let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
        player = try! AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: filePath as URL)
        player.numberOfLoops = -1 //logic for infinite loop
        player.prepareToPlay() 
        player.play()
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try!audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers)
}
```

The below code is for ON and OFF.

```
@IBAction func firePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if fireOnoff.isHidden == true {

        fireOnoff.isHidden = false
        infoPopup.isHidden = true
        popViewslider.isHidden = true
        videoContolpopup.isHidden = true
        volumePopup.isHidden = true

    }
  if player.isPlaying {

        player.pause()
        onoffLabel.textAlignment = .center
        onoffLabel.text = "Off"
    } else {

        player.numberOfLoops = -1
        player.play()
        onoffLabel.textAlignment = .center
        onoffLabel.text = "On"

    }

    toggleButton(button: sender, onImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "selectedfire "), offImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "unselectedfire"))
}
```

I am building for iOS and tvOS. Both face same problem.
Do you have any suggestions for resolving this? Thanks in advance!!

Edit: I have already turned on the Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture in Background Modes capabilities.

Comment: Turn on the Background Modes for Audio, AirPlay...

Comment: @JigneshChanchiya Already done! Still facing the same issue